# "Resource not available. Please try again later" error when accessing Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager

When trying to access google analytics for re marketing tags facing the below issue. Just wondering if anyone faced this issue before:

[image]

Comment: Did you pass this at last?

Comment: yes.. It worked in the very next day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an error on server side, try it in a few minutes or hours and it will probably work again. Page refresh sometimes works.